# 2-step verification in xmpp protocol

Tags: gmail, xmpp, protocols, gmail-imap

Recently I turned my gmail account into 2-step verification ON.Now when I try to connect my gmail account through any jabber(xmpp supported) clients.. it wont work.I know gmail is based on xmpp protocol.Does xmpp protocol support 2step verification or its  a different set of process.. please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMPP still should work.  You will be required to generate a application password for each client (e.g. XMPP client, phone, etc.).

http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185833